# Dataframe - Pandas - The result of subtracting the columns is wrong?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a dataframe  with below details:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 13323270 entries, 0 to 13323269
Data columns (total 10 columns):
 #   Column                 Dtype  
---  ------                 -----  
 0   SellerID               int64  
 1   RateID                 int64  
 2   payment_types          int64  
 3   fare                   float64
 4   extra_tax              float64
 5   inline_tax             float64
 6   tariff_amount          float64
 7   tolls                  float64
 8   surcharge              float64
 9   total_amount           float64
```

total_amount is the sum of (fare + extra_tax + inline_tax + tariff_amount + tolls + surcharge)

To check the values, the below codes are executed:

```
df['amount_check'] = df.loc[:, 'total_amount'] - df.loc[:, 'fare'] - df.loc[:, 'extra_tax'] -
                     df.loc[:, 'inline_tax'] - df.loc[:, 'tariff_amount'] - df.loc[:, 'tolls'] -
                     df.loc[:, 'surcharge']
```

The above codes should result in zero for all rows. But surprisingly it is not, and there are some negative values there in 'amount_check' column.

To check the total_amount, I do the same in a new column:

```
df['total_amount_new'] = df.loc[:, 'fare'] + df.loc[:, 'extra_tax'] + df.loc[:, 'inline_tax'] + 
                         df.loc[:, 'tariff_amount'] + df.loc[:, 'tolls'] + df.loc[:, 'surcharge']
```

Then the results of **total_amount** and **total_amount _new** are the same!

Why this happens? What is wrong with the subtracting operation?

Comment: it is possible to call the columns as `df['column']`

Comment: It would help if you posted a sample of the data, particularly the rows where things don't seem to be working.  And as @AlvaroMartinez said, you can simply reference `df['fare']` instead of `df.loc[:, 'fare']`.